# How can we open webpage in unity application without opening it in default browser?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, windows-app-sdk

I want to open a webpage in unity windows application, i don't want to open the webpage in default browser. Because i don't want user to access browser from application.

I tried external packages but i don't want to use external package

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't natively support displaying web pages, so an external package is required. To avoid using additional packages, one option would be to render a web page as an image and display it in a 3D object in Unity. However, this is static and does not allow direct interaction. For an interactive solution, it is recommended to use external Unity Asset Store packages that support WebView, such as **UniWebView**, for example.